# Bluetooth is broken in 15.10?

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-15.10

After upgrading to ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04 bluetooth stopped receiving or sending files. Connection is made correctly both ways. When sending to ubuntu my android device tells me that "Transfer is forbidden on receiving device". When sending from ubuntu via blueman an error occures:
_on_properties_changed (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/obex/Transfer.py:54)
/org/bluez/obex/client/session2/transfer4 Status error

gnome-file-share-properties is configured correctly.
blueman-services I configured to receive files.

Comment: I think this is the wrong forum - Perhaps the superuser one might be better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on superuser

Comment: A little late now that it's on SuperUser, but wouldn't Ask Ubuntu have been a better option?